# jquery rotating text animation (recreating css3 effects)

Tags: jquery

Does anybody know if there is a jquery plugin that does something similar to this effect?
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3RotatingWords/index5.html

i like the effect, but i need it to be compatible down to IE7, or at least, just display the text for those rotating words in IE9/8/7

Comment: I don't think it's possible to create the same blur effect when fading out, in older browsers. But you could degrade to a simple fade. Is this a problem?

Comment: no, i think that would work also. i really just want to be able to have the text show up in anything <IE9. IE browsers don't have to actually do the effect.

Comment: Ok, then it's easy to implement. I'll write a fiddle for you

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the page (possibly in a separate js file), after jQuery

```
(function($){
    $.fn.rotate = function(params){
        return this.each(function(index, el){
            var defaults = {
                text : [],
                interval : 2000
            };

            var options = $.extend({}, defaults, params);
            var i = 0;

            if(options.text.length){
                setInterval(function(){
                    i = i < options.text.length -1 ? ++i : 0;
                    $(el).fadeOut(function(){ 
                        $(this).text(options.text[i]).fadeIn();
                    });
                }, options.interval);
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

To use it, just do

```
$(selector).rotate({ 
    text: ['text1', 'text2'] // an array of strings
    interval: 2000 // Optional. number in milliseconds, I've put default as two seconds  
});
```

Take a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U9ZTa/1/

you may change it according to your needs. The fading effect should work on all browsers IE6+.

And you can add that css animation in modern browsers if you want to...

Answer (score 0):

This might help - jQuery simple text rotator: http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/jquery_super_simple_text_rotator_demo.html

You might need to adjust this to be able to get the same effect on the link you provided.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I was kinda new here when I posted this answer.